Remove song from audio track where song is recorded on another track
I have an audio file with two tracks: one with me talking over music playing on a speaker, and another track of just the music. I know I can use an off the shelf voice isolation tool to extract just my voice, but is there a way to do this better by using that audio track of just the song?
